# Chaba''d doesn't follow minhag hamakom?

Tags: tefilla, minhag, chabad, nuschaot

My shul davens "standard" Nusach Sfard. During Shabbat mincha, the sha''tz was a Chaba''d chasid. While we were returning the Torah, the sha''tz started saying Kaddish. (Nusach Chaba''d/Ari only says one paragraph: *Yehallelu*.) Also, as it was R' Schneerson's *yahrtzeit* last Shabbat, the sha''tz also did not say *Tzidkatcha Tzedek*.

After he finished davening, the gabbai asked him why he didn't follow *minhag hamakom* (the minhag of the shul that he is in, now). He responded that Nusach Ari is the only "authentic" nusach, and that Chaba''d *never* follows minhag hamakom.

I know nothing about this aspect of Chaba''d practice, and the gabbai was surprised to hear this. (As a matter of fact, he was annoyed.) Can someone verify if in fact this is Chaba''d "policy", or if this person was misinformed?

Comment: Probably misinformed. Note also that not saying *Av HaRachamim*/*Tzidkatcha Tzedek* then is highly controversial within Chabad itself.

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but isn't it a political question? I indeed know synagogues that were taken over by Chabad in similar ways, while I also know Mizrachi Chabad Jews, who follow the standard Eidot haMizrach nusach.

Comment: I am literally rolling my eyes right now. Nusach Ari is _not_ the only "authentic" nusach. That's just more Chabad superiority complex. I can't tell you how many times I've heard that one. Gosh, I daven Nusach Ari but saying it's the most "authentic" nusach is absurd. Tell the gabbai I'm so sorry for the chutzpah that happened here.

Comment: On a more related note, IIRC the Lubavitcher Rebbe insisted that his Chasidim not wear tefillin on Chol HaMoed, _even_ in a shul whose minhag _is_ to wear tefillin. That's one instance where Chabad trumps minhag hamakom. (As you probably know, the halacha is usually that one whose minhag is to not wear tefillin on Chol HaMoed prays with a minyan whose minhag _is_ to wear tefillin, he should put on tefillin without a bracha.)

Comment: @ezra The Tefillin example is a little different. While I don't know the reason for Chabad, other authorities as well are lenient with regards to not putting on Tefillin on Chol Hamoed in a Shul that does. As long as one isn't 'making a statement' when he isn't putting on the Tefillin, it's no different than any other day when one doesn't put on Tefillin during davening for any other reason (i.e. upset stomach, forgot them at home, etc.).

Comment: @ezra The idea of not wearing tefilin on *Chol HaMoed* even in a shul which does is far from a "Chabad" thing. There are many others that do that too (See e.g. *S'dei Chemed* on the topic). On a personal note I have davened on *Chol HaMoed* many times with these "Pesach programs" and there were many that put on and many didn't.

Comment: @ezra I should have mentioned that the conversation was eventually relayed to me by the gabbai after Shabbat. I suspect that, perhaps, part of it was the gabbais feelings about it and may not have been part of hwat the shat"z really told him. I can't tell for certain. I can vouch for what actually happened during mincha, which, is the main point of my question. With your being Chaba"d, perhaps you can verify if this "minhag hamakom" claim is Chaba"d policy or not. I agree with the gabbai on this, and I understand why he was annoyed. Tefillin on Hol Hamo'ed is a separate issue.

Comment: @DanF From my experience, Chabad ignores minhag hamakom.

Comment: @ezra Initial reaction - I find that disturbing. If this is the case, I can see, at least this gabbai, verifying if someone is Chaba"d before he lets him become *shat"z*.  I would love to see you post an answer explaining why.

Comment: Pretty sure that sounds like lo tisgoditu but ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like someone who didn't know what they were doing. There is no minhag in chabad to skip tachanun for a yartzeit. Those that skip tachanun on gimmel tammuz do so as a personal hergish bc of the connection to the rebbe rayatz but this should not be forced on others and he should follow community guidelines as the chazan. There is no source for claiming the the chabad nusach is the only valid one and in fact in the introduction to the teholas Hashem siddur there is an explanation of why there are multiple nusachos. In conclusion there is nothing about what this person did which is chabad policy.

Comment: On a side note in regard to returning the Torah on shabbos minhag the chabad custom is to say kaddish slowly as the Torah is returned and not say any of the verses accompanying the carrying the Torah including the one in the siddur.

Comment: Are you Chaba"d, yourself, or how do you know for certain that this is Chaba"d policy?

Comment: Yes I am a lubavitcher and what this person allegedly did was arrogant. Claiming that only what you do is right is the farthest thing from chabad policy possible

Comment: This hasn't been my experience with Chabad. :) Depending on the Lubavitcher, they can be a little "pushy" when it comes to minhagim.

Comment: @Ouch! I've seen a variety. Come to NY, and you'll see it all ... and more! Dude - thanks for the info. I'm disturbed that I had to hear about this in this way. As I said, though, while I did watch what occurred, I heard the conversation part third-party. I suspect that the gabbai who relayed the story to me may have added his personal bias to the conversation. At any rate, that doesn't affect my admiration of Chabad's work, in general. Esp. in college campuses in the U.S., Chaba"d is frequently a spiritual life-saver. Maintain the great work!

Comment: @Dude Why would skipping tachanun on Gimmel Tammuz be because of a connection to the Rebbe Rayatz as opposed to the Rebbe?

Comment: Some do for that reason and this is dependent on the individual; however, the actual chabad minhag is celebrating the release of the rebbe rayatz on yud bes and yud gimmel tammuz.